# navigation active link highlight

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create a navigation link where when i click on a link it highlights to a different color but when i click on the next one the previous link gets un highlighted and the most recent link clicked gets the highlight

heres the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/JCzvL/22/

right now its just highlighting all the links

html

```
  <span class="tab1"><a class="slider_link" href="#1" rel="welcome">Comics</a></span>
  <span class="tab2"><a class="slider_link" href="#2" rel="hatstory">Media</a></span>
  <span class="tab3"><a class="slider_link" href="#3" rel="annoyed">Bat News</a></span>​
```

jquery

```
$('a.slider_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).removeClass('slider_link_style');
    $(this).addClass('slider_link_style');
    return false;
})
```

css

```
.slider_link_style{color: white}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the class from the "cousin" links, not from `this`:

```
$('a.slider_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).closest('span').siblings().find('a').removeClass('slider_link_style');
    $(this).addClass('slider_link_style');
    return false;
})​; ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JCzvL/24/

Comment: Why not just remove it from all the links and save several function calls?

Comment: @Madbreaks  Because for all I know, there are other `a` elements elsewhere on the page that shouldn't have that class removed.

Comment: There could be other `a` siblings that shouldn't have the class removed either.

Comment: @Madbreaks Not in OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

Just tweak your `removeClass` call slightly:

```
$('a.slider_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    //
    // Remove class from *all* a.slider_links:
    //
    $('a.slider_link').removeClass('slider_link_style');
    $(this).addClass('slider_link_style');
    return false;
});
```

Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/a892N/

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, your code is targeting exclusively the clicked element so when you remove the class, you're just removing it from itself, not the other elements in the menu. By changing the selection like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5nVm/), you manage to achieve your desired result.

```
  $('a.slider_link').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $('a.slider_link').removeClass('slider_link_style');
      $(this).addClass('slider_link_style');
      return false;
  });
```

Or if you want to reuse the selector to jump lest times into the pool, this should give you a slight performance improvement, since you're not parsing the DOM twice for the same selection.

```
var menu_items = $('a.slider_link');
menu_items.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    menu_items.removeClass('slider_link_style');
    $(this).addClass('slider_link_style');
    return false;
})
```

Comment: what if i wanted to automatically highlight a link when the user first hits the page....like what if i wanted comics to be pre highlighted since its the first one

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler, the `this` reference points to the item that was clicked. Therefore you are removing and re-adding the slider_link_style CSS class to the same element. Try this:

```
$('a.slider_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('a.slider_link').removeClass('slider_link_style');
    $(this).addClass('slider_link_style');
    return false;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JCzvL/23/

Answer (score 0):

Setup *Event Delegation* so you don't have multiple handlers listening on multiple elements. Instead, just listen for a bubbling click event on a common ancestor. For instance, I setup a `#links` parent:

```html
<nav id="links">
    <span class="tab1">
        <a class="slider_link" href="#1" rel="welcome">Comics</a>
    </span>
    <span class="tab2">
        <a class="slider_link" href="#2" rel="hatstory">Media</a>
    </span>
    <span class="tab3">
        <a class="slider_link" href="#3" rel="annoyed">Bat News</a>
    </span>
</nav>
```

Now use `$.on` to bind up the delegation. When any anchor within `#links` is clicked, we remove our target class from any other anchors in the delegateTarget, and add it to the link that triggered the click event to begin with:

```js
$("#links").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    $(event.delegateTarget).find("a").removeClass("slider_link_style");
    $(this).addClass("slider_link_style");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JCzvL/25/